# Errors with `interfaces` package in TeXLive 2021

Tags: texlive-2021, interfaces

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{interfaces-makecell}
\begin{document}
    xxx
\end{document}
```

When compling using `xelatex` of TeXLive 2021 in `overleaf`, the errors are:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interfaces/interfaces-scrlfile.sty, line 55
Package etoolbox Error: \scr@load@hook undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.55 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@load@hook
                                   [2]{%
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interfaces/interfaces-scrlfile.sty, line 59
Package etoolbox Error: \scr@set@load@hook undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.59 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@set@load@hook
                                       [2]{\csgappto{#2-@#1}}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interfaces/interfaces-pgfkeys.sty
Package: interfaces-pgfkeys 2011/02/19 v3.1 pgfkeys handlers definitions (FC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interfaces/interfaces-tikz.sty
Package: interfaces-tikz 2011/02/19 v3.1 load tikz libraries easily (FC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interfaces/interfaces-umrand.sty
Package: interfaces-umrand 2011/02/19 v3.1 patch for umrand.sty ifnotempty (FC))) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: XeTeX
(|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count190
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count191
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
\g__graphics_track_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count194
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count195
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count196
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux
```

BTW: compiling using `xelatex` in TeXLive 2020 and older has no error.

Comment: Interfaces is imho unmaintained and so no longer keeps track of the packages it patches. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: `interfaces` (`interfaces-scrlfile`) appears to patch an internal command from `scrlfile` that is no longer present in the current version of `scrlfile` because the package now relies on the available LaTeX hooks. You could try to contact the `interfaces` author about this, but the package was last updated ten years ago, so you may not have much luck. It's probably best to avoid the package for now.

Comment: The package author has produced a few interesting packages, but has a history of abandoning them. One of the reasons may be that these packages often rely on heavily changing internals of other packages and of the LaTeX kernel itself, so they're quite likely to break in case of updates.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind helps, @egreg @moewe @Ulrike Fischer. Maybe I should find an alternative way instead of using the `interfaces` package, but that might be another question.